# tooling API workflow alert update

Tags: workflow, tooling-api, apex-webservice

i am trying to update workflow alert email template using tooling api. REST AND PATCH . 
JSON body is below

```
{"Metadata":{"ccEmails":["test@gmail.com"],
                        "description":"sendMassEmailsThroufhWorkFlow",
                        "protected":"false",
                        "senderType":"CurrentUser",
                        "template":"folderNAMES1/SingleEmailMassTemplate"
}}
```

i am getting below error

> [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from
>   VALUE_STRING value CurrentUser at [line:1,
>   column:138]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

if we remove `senderType` parameter, then below error value will come

> [{"message":"Required field is missing:
>   senderType","errorCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION","fields":[]}]

looks like when we add sender type  paarmeter, parser is failing . but this is one the required parameter. 
is there any example for updating workflow   email alert using tooling api ?

Comment: try doing a REST query on an existing workflow email alert with a ccEmails to verify proper construction of your JSON

Comment: we have tried this approach earlier. We first made GET in rest API and then took same structure and tried making PATCH call. it did not work.